# Webapi receive json with brackets

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

I just want to understand,
I spend days trying to solve an issue that POST operation wasn't working (using Web Api & Angular JS).
I thought about everything, trying, searching, I even change the code a thousand times. After that, I discovered that `POST` worked when `JSON` format was like this:

```
{"Name":"Test","Age":23}
```

but if I used `JSON.stringify(options.models);`

POST operation didn't work, Its format was like this:

```
[{"Name":"Test","Age":23}]
```

I don't understand what's the difference between them (Regardless to brackets `[]`)

Why the first one worked but the second one was not?

Is there a way to make the second format work?

Is the second one is an Array of JSON?

Shouldn't `JSON.stringify(options.models)` return a JSON format?

Class:

```
 public class EmployeesData
        {
            public EmployeesData() { }
            public EmployeesData(int Id, string Name, int Age, int Phone,string Job, string Department)
            {   this.ID = Id;
                this.Name = Name;
                this.Age = Age;
                this.Phone = Phone;
                this.Job = Job;
                this.Department = Department;}

            [Required]
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }

        }
```

In WebApi:

```
    [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(EmployeesData))]

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]EmployeesData employeesData) 
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
              return BadRequest(ModelState);}

            db.Employees.Add(employeesData);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employeesData.ID }, employeesData);
        }
```

In Angularjs:

```
parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
        if (operation !== "read") {
             console.log(kendo.stringify(options));
              console.log(JSON.stringify(options.models)); // Not work because of []
             var R = JSON.stringify(options.models).replace(/]|[[]/g, ''); // work I removed []
                                console.log(operation + R);

                             return (R);
                            }


                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What is the function prototype of the WebApi function you are trying to call?

Comment: Can you update the question instead of posting a comment.  It makes the code easier to read.  Also, can you post the `EmployeesInfo` class, I suspect this is the cause of the issue..

Comment: I update the question could you please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the mentioned format(`{"Name":"Test","Age":23}` and `[{"Name":"Test","Age":23}]`) means two different contract.

First one just an object and second one collection of objects.

Suppose if you are sending `{"Name":"Test","Age":23}` from angular then your Api controller method should be like

```
public void Demo(Test test)
{
  ///code here 
}
```

where Test would be

```
public class Test 
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

and if the you are sending [{"Name":"Test","Age":23}] then your Controller should be like

```
public void Demo(ICollection<Test> test)
{
  ///code here 
}
```

Comment: Great ! In ICollection Can you do something like this test.Name ?

Comment: You can't do `test.Name` in a collection, but you can do it on one item in the collection.

Comment: In collection if you want do test.Name you should iterate it. 
for eg: 
`foreach(var item in test)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
`